# Preview: Fullscreen movie turns black after 5s

Tags: macos, preview, movie

When I open a movie in preview (tested with .mov and .wmv), and I go to full screen, the movie turns black after five seconds, unless I keep moving the mouse. The movie plays just fine in windowed mode, and the issue occurs both on external and internal monitor, and with Caffeine turned on or off.

I assume there's a timeout setting somewhere. How can I modify this so that I can watch an entire movie in preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a [known bug with Pathfinder](http://forum.cocoatech.com/showthread.php?7425-Lion-issue-Quick-Look-does-not-work-in-full-screen-mode&highlight=preview%20fullscreen) that doesn't interact well (yet) with Quick Look. As a workaround, you can use Quick Look from Finder.